# Pipeline Serverless deploy fails on dependency install

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

We are using AWS Lambda and I'm trying to automate our deployment. The serverless-offline package generates an error on serverless build.

This is a multi-endpoint deployment. we'll be deploying multiple directories hence the `cd console` in the pipeline. We can deploy manually just fine using serverless deploy but my attempts to automate so far have come up empty.

My pipeline.yml

```
image: lambci/lambda:build-nodejs6.10
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: test
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g serverless
          - npm install -g serverless-offline
          - npm install -g serverless-domain-manager
          - cd console # will be doing this for multiple directories, but just using one for now
          - serverless plugin install --name serverless-webpack
          - serverless plugin install --name serverless-offline
          - serverless plugin install --name serverless-domain-manager
          - serverless create -t aws-nodejs
          - serverless deploy
```

my partial serverless.yml for that directory

```
# Use the serverless-webpack plugin to transpile ES6
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager

# serverless-webpack configuration
# Enable auto-packing of external modules
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  customDomain:
```

I've tried installing using

`npm install -g serverless-offline`

and

`- serverless plugin install --name serverless-offline`.

If I miss either of these I get the error

`Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file.`

but now I get

`Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" initialization errored: Unexpected identifier`

when I'm running the serverless create step.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, I needed to install serverless globally but npm install inside of the directory:

```
          - npm install -g serverless          
          - git log --grep=console
          - cd console
          - npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add serverless with your version in devDependencies in package.json file as:

```
"devDependencies": {
"serverless": "1.72.0",
 ....
 }
```

then add a custom command in your scripts section

```
"scripts": {
  "sls:deploy": "serverless deploy",
   .....
 }
```

then in your pipeline.yml

```
- npm i
- npm run sls:deploy
```